# Time Stamp is Returning Year in Seconds for Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, jupyter

I have data that has a "YEAR" column. The second column is "JFK", which is the wind speeds. I need to convert the YEAR column to show arbitrary months and time. But it needs to keep the year.

For instance, I have some data at the year 1972. I want it the column to read:

1972-01-01 00:00:00.000000000

But instead, I am getting:

1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001972

When I type the following:

```
winds["YEAR"] = pd.to_datetime(winds["YEAR"],errors='ignore')
```

For some reason, the year is showing up in seconds. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to parse the given column into a datetime and then format the resulting datetime into a string.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1972]})
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000000')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                            year
0  1972-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `format=%Y`

```
winds["YEAR"] = pd.to_datetime(winds["YEAR"],format='%Y')
```

Also, this solution assume that your input is an integer/float since it would correctly parse a string without the need for format.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the year: 1972-01-01. But is there any way to get the seconds back?

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to output `1972-01-01 00:00:00`? If so, can you check the exact output you are receiving now and share in the comments. Type `winds["YEARS"].values[0]`

Comment: Yes. I would like it to still show: 1972-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: That is a separate question from the original. One that can be solved using [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html). Which convert it to string of specified formatting.